Set a label caption in a Userform by selecting an address from the global address book
In an Outlook userform, I want to caption a label ("CourrielSup") using an email address selected from the global address list.
Using the SelectNamesDialog.Display method from the Microsoft knowledge base I get access to the global address book. When I click the command button "ListeAdresse", the dialog box displaying the address book pops up.
I can't find a way to have the selected email address become the caption of my label.
Private Sub ListeAdresse_Click()
 Dim Courriel As String
 Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog
 Set oDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
 With oDialog
 .InitialAddressList = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList
 If .Display Then
    CourrielSup.Caption = .Recipients
 End If
 End With
End Sub


Caption expects a string but .Recipients is a Collection...

This works for me:
Sub ListeAdresse_Click()
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
 
    Dim dlg As SelectNamesDialog, recip As Recipient
    
    Set dlg = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
    
    With dlg
        .InitialAddressList = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList
        If .Display Then
            Set recip = .Recipients(1)
            'get the address property
            Debug.Print recip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

GetProperty:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.propertyaccessor.getproperty

Wow, that is a much prettier code than my solution ! Thanks a bunch ! I'll look into the GetProperty page.

Please flag as "Accepted" if this answered your question, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.

I ended up finding a way to make it work by making a frankencode using some lines from someone who had another problem related to SelectNamesDialog.Display.
I am fully aware that the resulting code is very ugly. If someone is kind enough to help me make it pretty, or to explain to me the logical difference between what i originally did ad this code, i would be thrilled.
Private Sub ListeAdresse_Click()

 Dim EmailAddress As String
 Dim myAddrEntry As AddressEntry
 Dim exchUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser
 Dim oDialog As SelectNamesDialog
 Set oDialog = Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog
 
 With oDialog
 .InitialAddressList = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList
 .ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = True

        If .Display Then

          AliasName = oDialog.Recipients.Item(1).Name

            Set myAddrEntry = Application.Session.GetGlobalAddressList.AddressEntries(AliasName)
            Set exchUser = myAddrEntry.GetExchangeUser

            If Not exchUser Is Nothing Then
               EmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

            End If
            CourrielSup.Caption = EmailAddress
   End If
    End With
Set olApp = Nothing
Set oDialog = Nothing
Set oGAL = Nothing
Set myAddrEntry = Nothing
Set exchUser = Nothing

End Sub

